# Mousedown jquery except or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I have the following javascript, I don't want this mousedown function to fire if the user is clicking on a delete div inside the .field_trip_mini_div. The delete div id is 'delete'. What code should I add so the mouse down function does not procede if the user clicked on the delete div? I tried changing the first line to

```
$(".field_trip_mini_div :not('#delete')").live({
```

But that didn't work. Is there a way I could stop it on the second line of code?

```
$(".field_trip_mini_div").live({  
    mousedown: function(){     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/field_trips/"+selected_field_trip_id+"/reload_div",
        data: {id: selected_field_trip_id},
        success: function(response)
           {
            $('#selected_fieldTrip_div').html(response);
           }
        });
});
```

Edit: I used # originally, thank you for the answers but it was a Stack Overflow input error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `delete` an element inside `field_trip_mini_div`? If so you can check the id of the target of the clicked element using `e.target`:

```
$(".field_trip_mini_div").live({  
    mousedown: function(e){    
      if ($(e.target).attr("id")!= "delete") // This line right here
      {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/field_trips/"+selected_field_trip_id+"/reload_div",
            data: {id: selected_field_trip_id},
            success: function(response)
               {
                $('#selected_fieldTrip_div').html(response);
               }
            });
      }
  });
```

Some info on events and the `event` object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: Thank you! Was exactly what I needed. I have never heard of the e.target either so that will be helpful in the future. Will give you credit in 6 minutes :).

Comment: No problem mate! Some info on the event object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp I'm sure you'll run into `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` too in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

As delete is id use #, I suggest you to use [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as `live is deprecated`.

```
$(".field_trip_mini_div :not('#delete')").live({
```

or you can skip the code when delete is clicked

```
$(".field_trip_mini_div").live({  
    mousedown: function(evt){    
    if (evt.target.id == "delete") 
       return;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/field_trips/"+selected_field_trip_id+"/reload_div",
          data: {id: selected_field_trip_id},
          success: function(response)
             {
              $('#selected_fieldTrip_div').html(response);
             }
          });        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(".field_trip_mini_div :not('#delete')").on({
```

Note: Don't use "live" as it is deprecated; use "on" instead.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to on instead of live.